# crontab is not showing git remote branches

Tags: git, cron

simple code in a shell script listing remote branches :

```
cd <directory>
git branch --remote > test2.log
```

works fine when run from command line, but when run by crontab - gives no result. Listing local branches works both ways though.

Couldn't find an answer anywhere. Asking for help.

Comment: How is your remote configured? If accessing it requires authorization, how are you (failing to) provide the necessary credentials to your cron job?

Comment: Getting remote branch probably requires authentication to the git repository server, which is handled for you under your login, but not under the credentials of the crontab job, which are different.

Comment: However, `git branch -r` is a local operation, it doesn't involve sending or receiving anything from/to the remote. The repo has local copies of remote repo's branches, and uses that regardless of the actual current state of remote server.

Comment: @RomainValeri Exactly. "Git fetch" works fine both from the console as from crontab, so it should not be a problem with connecting with bitbucket.

Comment: Cron itself has no problem with double hyphen. I suspect your editor is replacing `--foo` with `–foo` (em or en dash) when editing a crontab file, or something along these lines. Another possibility, but unlikely in this particular case, is that you have two or more versions of Git installed, and cron uses a particularly ancient one (but even ancient Git has `--list` etc).

Comment: @torek That's exactly what was going on. "whereis git" showed two instances - one git was version 2.17 and the other 1.7.1. Cron was using the latter which did not have "--remote" (but also did not have "--list").

Comment: Aha. Faulty memory on my part then, I thought 1.7 supported the `--list` spelling.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. Very interesting thing - from various variants of this command only the first one & the last one work in cron (while all six work in console):

1. git branch -r
2. git branch --remote
3. git branch --list -r
4. git branch --list --remote
5. git branch -l --remote
6. git branch -l -r

It seems like cron has a problem with double hyphen-minus (--) in git command options.

EDIT:

Following @torek suggestion: "whereis git" showed two instances of git - one was version 2.17 and the other 1.7.1. Cron was using the latter which did not have "--remote" and "--list" options.